# insert image (jpg)in Markdown jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to insert the image in the markdown Jupiter notebook, which I type the code: 

 but I have got the result as point crosse 
so your advice will be appreciated here 
[![type of image jpg, name p1][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the cell replacing ImageName.jpg with the file name of your image. Make sure that the image file is in the current directory.

```
<img src="./ImageName.jpg"/>
```

Then in the cell menu go to 'cell type' and select markdown. Now run or run all. That should do it.

Comment: I have added the above code in cell  and then run all, my director is C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts but still shown the same result

Comment: Try it without the full path or even ./. Only <img src="ImageName.jpg"/>  And make sure that your .jpg file is in the same directory as the .ipynb file.